# How can I find which European countries require headlights on during daytime?

Tags: europe, legal, driving, regulations, automobiles

I know that the driving law in several countries in Europe require headlights on during daytime, some of them only in winter.
But where can I find which countries have such a requirement?

**Just to clarify**: I'm looking to identify all such countries. I don't want everybody to add an answer with a single country.

Comment: Austria requires also to turn on the headlights always.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Required under certain conditions:**

> Outside populated areas: Italy, Hungary and Romania
>
> Indicated roads only: Portugal
>
> Motorcycles only: Belgium, France, Spain

**Recommended**:

> Germany, Spain, France

**Required at all times:**

> Bulgaria, Czech Republic, Denmark, Estonia, Finland, Iceland, Latvia, Lithuania, Macedonia, Montenegro, Norway, Poland, Russia, Serbia, Slovakia, Slovenia, Sweden, Switzerland ([from 2014](http://www.tcs.ch/de/test-sicherheit/verkehrssicherheit/via-sicura/automatisches-tagfahrlicht.php))

Note that all vehicles sold in EU since 2011 are required to have DRLs installed as per European Union Directive 2008/89/EC.

Sources:

- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daytime_running_lights)
- [Official EU press release](http://europa.eu/rapid/press-release_IP-11-133_en.htm)
- [SWOV factsheet](http://www.swov.nl/rapport/Factsheets/UK/FS_DRL.pdf)

Comment: What does DRL mean?

Comment: @Bernhard: Daytime running lights -- see question title update and the Wikipedia link in my post.

Comment: Also, newer motorcycles in India is coming with lights on always.

Answer (score 3):

In France :

Headlights always were required for motorcycles.

About cars, the law recently changed. New production cars must be equipped with so-called "day lights" that are often white LED strips around the real headlight bulbs. But older cars hare not forced to turn the daylights on all the time; this would be an issue since many cars with LCD dashboards have the display dimmed when the headlights are on, thus making it harder to read on a sunny day.